# How to map URLs to different methods based on the presence of query parameters (JAXB)

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jersey

I'm writing ReST services using JAXB/Jersey.  I would like to do different server-side processing and return a different response based on whether or not the URL has query parameters.  Example:

```
http://domain.com/Person
```

would map to a page documenting the available "Person" services, while

```
http://domain.com/Person?search="someName"
```

would return the results of a lookup on people.

I currently have a convention that users can get usage/documentation for each category of services by requesting the base URL (i.e., `http://domain.com/Person`, `http://domain.com/Facility`).  Also, documentation is returned in XML, JSON, HTML, or plain text, depending on the `Content-Type` header.

**Question 1:** Is this a good design for a ReST service?
**Question 2:** How can I map URLs to different responses based on whether the URL has query parameters?

Comment: I don't believe you can do this with Jersey via annotations, but you can with SpringMVC 3.0 via the @RequestMapping

Comment: @Trever Thanks; here's the documentation on that: [Spring 3 @RequestMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-advanced)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. I don't think it's a good design. Assuming the URL points a resource, I don't think that resources should differ only by query parameters. You can use a different content-type or to append the url. E.g. `http://domain.com/Person` and `http://domain.com/Person/search`
2. No. JAX-RS doesn't allow such differentiation. The differentiation is based on url itself (without query string) and on producing/consuming content-type.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I originally had it '/Person/search', but the boss wanted to see if we could do the query stuff.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, I would consider:

`http://domain.com/service/People` - Service Description

`http://domain.com/People` - List All People

`http://domain.com/People?search=someName` - List All People based on search criteria

`http://domain.com/People/1234` - List a Specific Person

Logically, the resources being presented are now more consistent. Meaning, if your search could return multiple people, the resource at /People is still a list of people.

The resource represented by /People is not a service description, but rather the actual people. Hence why I would pull it into a different URL.

Comment: Great thoughts. Very RESTful design. Thanks.